# Replacing surroundings of text in brackets when it occurs multiple times in a string

Tags: regex, r

I have a string containing LaTeX code, for example `\emph{some words here}` and I want to get Markdown syntax, for example,`*some words here*`. I tried:

```
s <- "some text in \\emph{italics} and some more ..."
pattern <- "\\\\emph\\{(.*)\\}"
gsub(pattern,"*\\1*", s)

> "some text in *italics* and some more ..."
```

However, I do not succeed at handling multiple occurences in one string.

```
s <- "some text in \\emph{italics} and some \\emph{more italics} and ..."
gsub(pattern,"*\\1*", s)

> "some text in *italics} and some \\emph{more italics* and ..."
```

I guess I need a non-greedy version which handles multiple occurrences, but I am not sure how to do it. Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you using `[ ]` character class for `{` ? Is `{` optional, since you used `?` with it.

Comment: no. sorry. I updated the question, to make it more succinct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use lazy `?` quantifier like this.

**Regex:** `\\\\emph{(.*?)}`

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cY0jG4/3)**

Comment: okay, that was simple. Thanks  :)

Comment: @MarkHeckmann: Did that solved your problem ? Because I asked few doubts. Might improve the solution.